# A little bool magic

Tags: programming-puzzle, c#

## Challenge

Given the following C# method:

```
private static bool Test(bool a, bool b)
{
    if (a && b) return false;
    if (a) if (b) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Supply the values `a` and `b` so that `true` is returned.

## Winning condition

The first entry who can supply the correct arguments to make the given method evaluate to `true` wins.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! All challenges here need an objective winning criterion such that a winner can be chosen if there are multiple submissions. It seems there might only be a single solution here, so this challenge might not be a good fit for PPCG. [For future challenges let me recommend the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can get feedback before the challenge goes live.

Comment: (That said, I *am* intrigued by this puzzle, it's just that normally there should be multiple possible solutions to a challenge for it to make sense around here.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner My bad sorry. But why can't there be only one solution? Its a puzzle and not a code-golf challenge.

Comment: Meta discussion is split on whether [programming puzzles without additional win criteria are on topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5585/20260), with conflicting answers being upvoted. I'd rather keep questions open when it's unsettled, so I'm voting to reopen. If you have opinions, please contribute them to the discussion.

Comment: Ah well, programming puzzles have a bit of a weird place in this community, despite being in the name (and it's been suggested several times to remove it there). The main problem is that only very few puzzles fit the spirit of the site. In any case, whether there *is* only one solution or not, this needs an objective winning criterion in case someone *does* find a second one.

Comment: @xnor Thanks for the reminder. I guess I'll reopen and let the community decide then.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Added a winning condition to my puzzle.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I don't know about this one. One can just execute this code 4 times and "brute force" the solution. I am generall open for this kind of challenge, but this one is way too trivial imo.

Comment: @DenkerAffe I don't think any of the four obvious parameter combinations work.

Comment: @DenkerAffe You can try the 4 common bool combinations but you will only end up with `false`

Comment: assuming there is a valid answer, this is an excellent question, regardless of whether it fits what we normally consider on topic.+1. I think one of the reasons we don't normally consider questions like this on topic is that every other question I've seen like this has been by a beginner, and the answer has been blindingly obvious.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh, my bad. I agree then, lets just see how the community responds to it.

Comment: Holy WOW this is a nice paradox, no idea how to solve it. :O

Comment: Is there any restriction on how much use of reflection is allowed?

Comment: @MartinBüttner You can use it of course - no restriction. Just don't change the method ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Just a note tho: My solution **does not** use reflection.

Comment: @Widi See that's why "first valid solution" might not be the best idea. You might get an uninteresting but working solution which just messes with some internals via reflection and then there's no incentive for anyone to go looking for a more interesting solution without reflection.

Comment: Are we strictly limited to C#, or can we implement this identically in another language and show a solution for that language?

Comment: @VoteToClose I think its a C# only problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool a, b;
    unsafe
    {
        int* pa = (int*)&a;
        int* pb = (int*)&b;
        *pa = 1;
        *pb = 2;
    }

        Console.Write(Test(a, b));
}
```

This prints `True` for me with the C# implementation that comes with Visual Studio 2015. I actually don't know any C#, but I figured I'd try to write some C code and see if it worked. I was hoping that the compiler would assume that True is always represented as 1 and use a bitwise AND. In Debug mode, this is indeed the case (it worked with Release too). It uses a bitwise AND for the first condition and two comparisons to zero for the second:

```
            if (a && b) return false;
002C2E92  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-3Ch]  
002C2E96  movzx       edx,byte ptr [ebp-40h]  
002C2E9A  and         eax,edx  
002C2E9C  and         eax,0FFh  
002C2EA1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
002C2EA4  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-44h],0  
002C2EA8  je          002C2EB2  
002C2EAA  xor         edx,edx  
002C2EAC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],edx  
002C2EAF  nop  
002C2EB0  jmp         002C2EE4  
            if (a) if (b) return true;
002C2EB2  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-3Ch]  
002C2EB6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax  
002C2EB9  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],0  
002C2EBD  je          002C2EDC  
002C2EBF  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-40h]  
002C2EC3  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax  
002C2EC6  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-50h],0  
002C2ECA  je          002C2EDC  
002C2ECC  mov         eax,1  
002C2ED1  and         eax,0FFh  
002C2ED6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
002C2ED9  nop  
002C2EDA  jmp         002C2EE4  
            return false;
002C2EDC  xor         edx,edx  
002C2EDE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],edx  
002C2EE1  nop  
002C2EE2  jmp         002C2EE4  
        }
002C2EE4  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
002C2EE7  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
002C2EEA  pop         ebx  
002C2EEB  pop         esi  
002C2EEC  pop         edi  
002C2EED  pop         ebp  
002C2EEE  ret
```

Comment: Amazing! I was totally sure that it could not be done

Comment: I have tried the same thing but it doesn't seem to work in Mono under Linux.

Comment: This would be dependent not on the C# compiler (currently Roslyn from MS) but rather on the JIT compiler (currently RyuJIT from MS). Though the IL the C# compiler produces could also affect what JIT does.